# Multiple View Controllers for 1 XIB for iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, android-mapview, xib

So i have an xib that has some UILabels and 1 MKMapView but the problem is that I'm using someone else's source code for getting the mapview, so i just copy/pasted the files into my project and did an #import.  the UILabels are set with my code, but i'm not sure how to get the third party's mapview into my XIB (the third party's source already had an XIB in it and i want to put that mapview into my XIB)

is there an easy way to do this (is this a sane idea)?

Comment: the easiest way is to integrate your code with others code don't do just copy and paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need just a MKMapView i would recommend doing it by yourself for some reasons:

- You learn how to do things.
- You know exactly what's going on (because you have done it yourself).
- Its quick and simple.

If the code you are using as some complex logic that would be complicate to reproduce/create by yourself, I would take some time to understand what's going on and use it. If not, and you only need a MKMapView, use this tutorial to get things going:

http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2009/04/02/iphone-sdk-30-playing-with-map-kit/